# Keep strips height when pressing home

Tags: video-sequence-editor, edit-mode, video

I am still trying to get familiar with Blender's interface, to use it for video editing.

Now, when you press the home button, it shrinks the strips in order to see the whole timeline. I would like to know if there is any way to use this option but keeping the height of the strips that i set.

Comment: Don't forget, you can scale the view with Ctrl+MouseMouseButton with individual control over height and with.

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to change this behaviour.

> **View all Sequences** <kbd>Home</kbd>
>   Zooms the display to show all strips.

But there is a similiar command.

> **View Selected** <kbd>NumpadPeriod</kbd>
>   Zooms in the display to fit only the selected strips.

This will zoom to the selection. An alternative would be to quickly select all then view selected.

<kbd>A</kbd>, (<kbd>A</kbd>,) <kbd>NumpadPeriod</kbd>

This will preserve the height scale.

Answer (score 1):

Pressing Home key will scale all strips to the current view. You can split your VSE timeline to a second view with all clips, use this to navigate and select strips, then in the larger view press Numpad Period. The preview window will still show the current frame from either timeline.

[image: VSE navigate]